# A season of this tv series has the protagonist stranded on a wild west planet

Tags: story-identification, tv, space, episode-identification

All statements subject to memory corruption. Considering my age, I probably saw it no earlier than 2000.

The protagonist is a white male adult. The first of the episodes ends with his scream and a segue into zooming off the planet to something in space. I remembered that when seeing [these seconds from Happy Feet](https://youtu.be/wV4M9_M0-Ag?t=184) and ask here to see that episode's end again.

Each further episode starts/ends with such a zoom to frame what's happening.

The space object maybe looked [kinda geometrical](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/8-cell-orig.gif) and may be a necessary way point to get out of there.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! It's great that you've read [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) before asking. Most people don't!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make me think of [Gene Roddenberry's Andromeda's fifth season](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0213327/episodes?season=5&ref_=tt_eps_sn_5) (2005).

While the 4 previous seasons of the show are a classic "star-trecky" show, the 5th season stranded the team on a 'classic' space-western planet.

The main hero is played by Kevin Sorbo (more prominently known by playing *Hercules* before).

[image: Andromeda promotional image with Kevin Sorbo and the later seasons' main cast]

The system is isolated and the only way in/out seems to be a space phenomenon called the Route of Ages (which is depicted as a giant, glowing [tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract), a 4-dimensional hypercube).

[image: Route of Ages]

Answer (score 2):

Some things here remind me of *[Earth 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_2_(TV_series))*, a one-season television "space western" series that first ran from 1994-1995, although it was rerun occasionally in syndication in later years.

The main character is female, but there is adult male deuteragonist, John Danziger, portrayed by Clancy Brown (playing against type as one of the heroes).

Per Wikipedia:

> [T]he ship arrives at G889, but it crash lands a great distance from the planned landing site. With her group scattered on the planet and supplies missing, Devon marshals what survivors she can find and begins heading west to the planned site of New Pacifica.
>
> During their travels, Adair and her companions slowly learn to cope with life on the alien world, which at first seems superficially Earth-like but which is gradually revealed to have a very different ecology, including two different native sentient and humanoid species—a short and stout race at the level of development of hunter-gatherers with a propensity towards kleptomania known as "Grendlers" and the much taller and lankier "Terrians", who are capable of telepathic communication, can tear rents and tunnels in the earth through a pseudo-psychic process and whose well-being is somehow linked to that of the planet. The survivors also learn that the Council — a government group that seems to wield most of the power on the space stations — wants to gain control of G889 for resettlement. Through their various experiments, they have learned that they cannot remove the Terrians without killing the planet. This complicates matters, because Devon's son, who has been healed by the Terrians and who had begun to exhibit some of their unique characteristics, has become the key to the Council's plan for the planet.

The styling on many of the futuristic objects on the show had a distinctly geometric character, for example:

[image: Main cast]

[image: Vehicle cab]

[image: Domes]